# How do you measure performance for go app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, profiling

I'm just starting development on App Engine using Golang. I noticed Go doesn't have appstats.

Could you please tell me your workflow for a Go App Engine project? Things from how you profiling to separating development environment from production.

Also, any tips would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I'm using app engine logs , you can see the trace of the request- response action

Comment: There is one third-party package that works great, here it is: http://godoc.org/github.com/mjibson/appstats

Comment: Thank you for the response. It's kinda hard to visualize data as a glance from a log file. There is this appstats for golang by a developer, but it requires functions to adhear to it's structure func(context, r, w) unlike the real appstats for python and java. https://github.com/mjibson/appstats
Any other tools?